# Smart contract deploy error: the feature lang_items is internal to the compiler or standard library

Tags: rust, multiversx, erdpy

I try to redeploy a MultiversX smart contract for which I haven't changed the code in a while. However, the deploy recently started to fail with this error:

```
error: the feature `lang_items` is internal to the compiler or standard library                                                      
  --> src/lib.rs:13:12
   |
13 | #![feature(lang_items)]
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: using it is strongly discouraged
   = note: `#[deny(internal_features)]` on by default
```

The issue is that this `![feature...]` is in an auto-generated file.

What is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be related to the rust version.

For example, `rustc 1.73.0 nightly` was incompatible with the framework.

Run `mxpy deps check rust` to see what version you have.

To downgrade the version you can use `mxpy deps install rust --tag=nightly-2023-04-24 --overwrite`.

A detailed conversation about this problem can be found on [here](https://t.me/MultiversXDevelopers/116983).